# jQuery ajax cannot insert + sign from html fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I click the submit button the field data is not saved if the text includes the `+` sign.

Text not including the `+` sign is ok.

```js
 function saveData(id) {
   var title = $('#title' + id).val();
   var description = $('#description' + id).val();
   var start = $('#start' + id).val();
   var end = $('#end' + id).val();
   var venue = $('#venue' + id).val();
   if (title == '') {
     alert('No title can be left blank\nPlease Fill in the field');
     return false;
   }
   var string = "event_id=" + id + "&title=" + title + "&description=" + description + "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end + "&venue=" + venue;
   $.ajax({
     url: "ajax-update.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: string,
     cache: false,
     beforeSend: function() {
       $("#save" + id).css("pointer-events", "none");
       $("#save" + id).html('saving.. .');
     },
     success: function(data) {
       if (data == 1) {

         $("#save" + id).html('Saved');
         var par = $("#save" + id).parent().parent();
         var tdTitle = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
         var tdDec = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
         var tdStr = par.children("td:nth-child(6)");
         var tdEnd = par.children("td:nth-child(7)");
         var tdVen = par.children("td:nth-child(8)");
         tdTitle.html(tdTitle.children('textarea').val());
         tdDec.html(tdDec.children('textarea').val());
         tdStr.html(tdStr.children('input').val());
         tdEnd.html(tdEnd.children('input').val());
         tdVen.html(tdVen.children('textarea').val());
       } else
         $("#save" + id).html('oops !');
     }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Because `+` is a reserved symbol in urls.

Comment: but i need to insert string like 500+ users what can do any suggation

Comment: Search for `encodeURI`/`encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Yeh buddy it's working thank for your suggation